# Codecov, Github actions and Angular 11 "No coverage report found"

Tags: angular, code-coverage, github-actions, codecov

I am trying to publish a code coverage of an Angular (v11) library to Codecov.io through Github actions

I have set it up the official Codecov github actions from the marketplace

```
name: tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    # Machine environment:
    # We specify the Node.js version manually below, and use versioned Chrome from Puppeteer.
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js 14
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build-lib
      - name: Test
        run: npm run test-lib-headless

      - name: Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1.1.1
```

task in package.json

```
"test-lib-headless": "ng test ngx-scrollbar --watch=false --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage",
```

**karma.conf.js**

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    capabilities: {
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--headless"]
      },
      'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
  });
};
```

The coverage files are created in the `coverage` directory

[image]

In Github actions CI, it shows that codecov didn't find the files!

[image]

Why is the files not found even that they were generated locally? does Codecov look for different report extension? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because default generated coverage report is not supported by codecov.

Simple solution is just adding `lcov` reporter to your config.

https://istanbul.js.org/docs/advanced/alternative-reporters/#lcovonly

```
coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/peach-tree'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'lcovonly' },
      ]
    },
```

Then bash script provided from codecov will upload your report without any issue.